# how can I solve this 'error: can't find module node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'

Tags: node.js, react-native, runtime-error

i tried to run my project with the 'npm run android' command and got this error. Please help me with this problem.

i already tried uninstalling the 'node_modules' folder and ran the commmand 'npm install', still not solved.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxsK2.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

What causes this error to happen is just the path of the project including Turkish characters. Then I moved my project to another folder with an English name based location, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Run this Command in your CLI of your project

```js
npm i @react-native-community/cli
```

Comment: i did. still the same error.

Comment: Use ```npx react-native run-android```

Comment: that did not solve too

Comment: like error said, bin.js was not exist in the /cli/build/ location, and the command you suggested 'npm i @react-native-community/cli' created bin.js and some other files and stuff. but still doesnt work. Help me pls.

Comment: still same error. bin.js not found in /cli/build/ folder.